# Passing arguments to a Java Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parameters

I did an android app, and I want to change some parameters of the running thread from the menu.
My class look like this:

```
public class MyClass {

        public class MyThread extends Thread {
             public volatile long sleepTime =200;
             .....
             public synchronized void set_sleepTime(long value)
                          /* with or without synchronized is te same problem*/

        {
            sleepTime=value;
        }
             .....
             }
}
```

I create the class in onCreateMethod of the Application

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyClass nClass=new MyClass(this);

        setContentView(nClass);

    }
```

I try to change the parameter in the menu. Like this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.load_game:
            ... 


                try{

                    mSheepThread.set_sleepTime(10);

                }
                catch (Exception e0)
                {
                    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not set parameters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                       ...              

        }
    }
```

I receive every time e0=NullPointer Exception.
I don't understand why.

Comment: You haven't shown nearly enough code. In particular, you haven't shown where `mSheepThread` is declared or assigned a value.

Comment: I bet mSleepThread is never initialised.

Comment: Imprecise question. Please say at least what is the `null` reference

Comment: Learn the Java naming conventions (which should be obvious by just looking at the javadoc), and stick to them. set_sleepTime -> setSleepTime. mSheepThread -> sheepThread.

Comment: Jon Skeet and jbx, you are right, I didn't initialised the mThreadSheep. I put the variable now like public class MyClass   {
 
 public static volatile long sleepTime =200;